# App Inventor choose background color from list in TinyDB

Tags: android, list, background-color, app-inventor, tinydb

I am trying to make an app using **App Inventor**.

The app has more functions, but I am stuck at the I would say "basic" one.
What I want to do is basically change the background color (or color of any element) by calling the color from list stored in `TinyDB`.

I have two screens Screen1 and a Menu screen.
I am tring to call `TinyDB` while Screen1 initializes and set background color of app on the first in the list. 
Further I want to let user to choose a color from list on the other screen "Menu". After picking a color change the color on both screens.

I tried to make it following the instruction https://sites.google.com/site/blocks123/playing-with-colors , but it is little bit confusing for me.

On the printscreen i have the `TinyDB` blocks on the Screen1. 
Is it possible on Screen1 just call/initialize `TinyDB` but has the `TinyDB` blocks on other screen "Menu"?

And when I have `TinyDB` and lists of color how to change the color on the chosen one?

[image]

Thank you Taifun. Your tutorial was helpful for me, evethought it is bit confusing with variables which aren´t described there. Anyway I tried to do it a bit on my way and I think I am going the right direction.
As it shown on second image I made it on the "Menu" screen and trying to save my choice to [TinyDB].
It works almost fine but except the error when "Menu" screen inicialize. I don´t understand why I am getting this message while to value is in the list? And the other way how to pass the BCurrentColor variable to "Screen1"? If I use set.Screen1.BackgroundColor it doesntWork

[image]

Well now I know I am close, I can almost fell it in the air. It is properly change background color on "Menu" screen but some how it doesn´t saves the choice to [TinyDB] as I describes at comments. Where I went wrong? 
I hope when I save the color "code" to database I can call it on the other screen.

[image]

Comment: do the [Colored Dots tutorial](http://explore.appinventor.mit.edu/ai2/colored-dots)...

Comment: Thank you Taifun. This tutorial was helpful for me, evethought it is bit confusing with variables which aren´t described there.

Anyway I tried to do it a bit on my way and I think I am going the right direction. 

As it shown on the other image I made i on the "Menu" screen and tring to save my choice to [TinyDB]. It works almost fine but except the error when "Menu" screen inicialize. 
I don´t understand why I am getting this message while to value is in the list?
And the other way how to pass the BCurrentColor variable to "Screen1"? If I use set.Screen1.BackgroundColor it doesntWork

Comment: there are some issues in your blocks. first of all, they are very cumbersome... variables `BCurrentColor` and `BCurrentColorName` should be values and not lists, it helps to learn how to work with lists, see also  [How to work with Lists](http://www.imagnity.com/tutorials/app-inventor/list-blocks-on-app-inventor/)  by Saj and [How to work with Lists and Lists of lists (pdf)](http://www.appinventor.org/bookChapters/chapter19.pdf) by appinventor.org. In case you still have problems, let me invite you to post in the [App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mitappinventortest).

Comment: A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles  
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Comment: Thank you I will study material from links. I would do it easier way but this is how I understand the sequence of steps. Can you please explain me what do you mean that variables BCurrentColor and BCurrentColorName should be values and not lists?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q&A site and not a forum, so extended discussions in the comments are unwanted here. As already recommended, ask in the [App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mitappinventortest) instead. And: you should have done the mentioned tutorials before asking there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Taifun mentioned the problem was with the variables `BCurrentColor` and `BCurrentColorName`. After I changed them to values and the trigger after selecting color from list sets it to required color.

Then I can call it from `TinyDB`. It works fine.